# Letor dataset format

Tags: dataset, information-retrieval

I just discovered the Letor dataset used for learning to rank problem. I'm wondering what are the last two columns "inc" and "prob" stands for in train/test/vali set? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I had the same question. Does anyone figure it out?

Comment: Same question. Looks like no one knows what's the meaning.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to [Introducing LETOR 4.0 Datasets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2597.pdf)
 on page 2: as explained in the article:

> Blockquote Each row is a query-document pair. The first column is relevance label of this pair,
>   the second column is query id, the following columns are features, and the end of
>   the row is comment about the pair, including id of the document. The larger the
>   relevance label, the more relevant the query-document pair

I hope it helps